# Accessing a file from multiple places on a server (php/ajax)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, file

I have a php script that opens a json file, rewrites it, then closes it. But there's also a site that needs to access that json file, so it's very likely that multiple users will be reading the contents of the json file with ajax while php is simultaneously changing the file.

I'm curious what this will do?

I'm assuming that it would cause some serious issues, would it be better to create a new file in php, make the changes, then rename and overwrite the old file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is, (unless you use flock : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php) there will probably be versions writing over other versions whose data they did not capture. In other words, there is a high likelihood of data loss.

Comment: if I want users to be able to access the file while I'm making changes to it would it be better to use flock($file, LOCK_SH) or flock($file, LOCK_NB)?

Comment: I'm not familiar with LOCK_NB, only LOCK_EX . If you want to write to the file, use LOCK_EX. After re-reading your question, your website scripts may want to use LOCK_SH if they will only be reading the file.. This will ensure that when your process that is writing to the file tries to get the lock with LOCK_EX, it will wait until all read locks are given up so you are assured no web processes are reading data until the write is complete.